# How to align the center of terms on left hand side of equations in 'aligned' environment in latex

Tags: equations, environments, page-breaking, box, aligned

In latex I defined a  new environment called 'myequation'. Here for left hand side terms, their end points are aligned. I want to align center points of left hand side terms instead of  their end points in addition to aligning the 'equal to' symbol. How can I modify my new environment to make this change. Also is it possible to make a page break in between some steps if I want and also put a particulat step in a box?

```
\documentclass[12pt, arrowdel]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\d{\mathrm{d}}
\def\pt{(\tau)}


%To align the equation number below for multiple line of equations
\newenvironment{myequation}{%
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
}{%
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{myequation}
    \dot{\rho} &= 3 \frac{\dot{a}}{a} \l(\rho + w \rho\r) =0\\
    \d \ln \rho &= -3\; \d \ln a (1+w(a))\\
    \int_{\rho_*}^{\rho} \d \ln \rho &= -3 \int_{a_*}^{a\pt}\d \ln a (1+w(a))\\
    \rho\pt  &= \rho_* e^{-3\int_{a_*}^{a\pt}\d \ln a (1+w(a))}
\end{myequation}
\end{document}
```

[image: The image of the equations in 'myequation' environment]

Comment: For center alignment, `align(ed)` is the wrog tool. You'll need an `array`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just curious, why you like to have math terms before equal sign centered? This appear (to my opinion, but I'm sure that at most people here, looks ugly :-(.

Comment: please fix your example, I added `\begin{document}` but it still errors with `LaTeX Warning: Command \r invalid in math mode on input line 15.
! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode`.   `\l` is a slashed l and `\r` is a ring accent, you should at least redefine them or (much) better adjust the example not to use non standard definitions of core latex functions. It just makes it harder to test answers.

Comment: In the final row, please, please replace `e^{-3\int_{a_*}^{a\pt}\d \ln a (1+w(a))}` with `\exp\biggl(-3\int_{a_*}^{a\pt}\d \ln a (1+w(a))\biggr)`.

Comment: thanks for the edit, but it's not good style to use `\def` it allows you to over-write core latex functionality with no warning, as here. Just hope you never need names such as `Ångstrom` in the bibliography as you have redefined that name to be an error.

Answer (score 1):

If I modify the example so that it produces output

[image]

Then you can add one extra `\hfil` into the preamble used by `aligned` so it centres, but the result is not really usable:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%To align the equation number below for multiple line of equations
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myequation}{%
\renewcommand{\start@aligned}[2]{%eek centred lhs
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}%
    \fi
    \savecolumn@ % Assumption: called inside a group
    \alignedspace@left
      \ams@start@box{##1}\bgroup
        \maxfields@##2\relax
        \ifnum\maxfields@>\m@ne
            \multiply\maxfields@\tw@
            \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@alignedat
            \alignsep@\z@skip
        \else
            \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@aligned
            \alignsep@\minalignsep
        \fi
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne
        \default@tag
        \spread@equation % no-op if already called
        \global\column@\z@
        \ialign\bgroup
           &\column@plus
            \hfil
            \strut@
            $\m@th\displaystyle{####}$%
\hfil%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \tabskip\z@skip
           &\column@plus
            $\m@th\displaystyle{{}####}$%
            \hfil
            \tabskip\alignsep@
            \crcr
          \ams@return@opt@arg
}%
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
}{%
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{myequation}
    \dot{\rho} &= 3 \frac{dot{a}}{a} (\rho + w \rho) =0\\
    d \log \rho &= -3\; d \log a (1+w(a))\\
    \int_{\rho_*}^{\rho} d \log \rho &= -3 \int_{a_*}^{ap}d \log a (1+w(a))\\
    \rho p  &= \rho_* e^{-3\int_{a_*}^{ap}d \log a (1+w(a))}
\end{myequation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please fix that "dota".

Comment: @barbarabeeton nah, it's irrelevant I just changed  `\d` to `d` because the OP did not define it (I changed `\ln` to `\log` for same reason, so the math is all wrong anyway, it's just filler text